# Jquery: Dynamic Loop table by its column and sum

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have these scenario, i would like to sum the

1) **unit x** on **Table A** with **unit x** on **Table B**

2) **unit y** on **Table A** with **unit y** on **Table B**

3) put the sum into **Table C** by its row index on **Table A** correspondingly

Below is my code, which is working fine:

**Table A:**

```
<table class="tableA" border='1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>JAN</td>
            <td>FEB</td>
            <td>MAR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit X</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="1" class="jan"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="2" class="feb"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="3" class="mar"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit Y</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="2" class="jan"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="2" class="feb"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="2" class="mar"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Table B:**

```
<table class="tableB" border='1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>JAN</td>
            <td>FEB</td>
            <td>MAR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit X</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="4" class="jan"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="4" class="feb"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="4" class="mar"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit Y</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="5" class="jan"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="5" class="feb"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="5" class="mar"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Table C:**

```
<table class="tableC" border='1'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>JAN</td>
            <td>FEB</td>
            <td>MAR</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit X</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" class="jan"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" class="feb"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" class="mar"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Unit Y</td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" class="jan"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" class="feb"></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" class="mar"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".tableA").find(".jan").each(function() { 
        var value_A = $(this).val();
        var row_index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        var value_B = $('.tableB').find("tr:eq("+row_index+") .jan").val();
        var sum = parseInt(value_A) + parseInt(value_B);
        $('.tableC').find("tr:eq("+row_index+") .jan").val(sum);
    }); 
    $(".tableA").find(".feb").each(function() { 
        var value_A = $(this).val();
        var row_index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        var value_B = $('.tableB').find("tr:eq("+row_index+") .feb").val();
        var sum = parseInt(value_A) + parseInt(value_B);
        $('.tableC').find("tr:eq("+row_index+") .feb").val(sum);
    });
    $(".tableA").find(".mar").each(function() { 
        var value_A = $(this).val();
        var row_index = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        var value_B = $('.tableB').find("tr:eq("+row_index+") .mar").val();
        var sum = parseInt(value_A) + parseInt(value_B);
        $('.tableC').find("tr:eq("+row_index+") .mar").val(sum);
    });    
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x3w5s3jx/)

**Problem:** current sum method are hard coded by its classname according to month, example: .jan .feb .mar

How do i do it dynamically to loop by its column without hard coded the classname, because the code will get longer until december.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for each function is generally the same (difference is really just the month. We can make this a generic function. i.e.

```
const processMonth = function($table, month) { 
    // Assume month = jan/feb/mar/...
    var value_A = $table.val();
    var row_index = $table.closest("tr").index();
    var value_B = $('.tableB').find("tr:eq("+row_index+") ." + month).val();
    var sum = parseInt(value_A) + parseInt(value_B);
    $('.tableC').find("tr:eq("+row_index+") ." + month).val(sum);
});
```

Now we can do something like

```
// Some months for brevity
const months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", ... "nov", "dec"];

months.forEach(function(month) {
    processMonth($(".tableA"), month);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming for each TD has only input[type="text"], then you can do the following. You can use class selector if you want.

```
$('.tableC input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    var indexTR = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    var indexTD = $(this).closest('td').index();

    var dataA = $('.tableA tr:eq(' + indexTR + ') td:eq(' + indexTD + ') input[type="text"]').val();
    var dataB = $('.tableB tr:eq(' + indexTR + ') td:eq(' + indexTD + ') input[type="text"]').val();

    var dataC = parseInt(dataA) + parseInt(dataB);
    $(this).val(dataC);
});
```